# Pseudoelements with background display odd outline in Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

When I apply background to an absolute positioned psudoelement in Chrome 40.0 on Android 4.4.2 (saw it on multiple devices and versions though) it displays extra pixel line on top and the bottom of the element. Is there any way to make it disappear?

Applied styles:

```
.el:before{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      background: url('/image.png') center top repeat-x;
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      z-index: 60 !important;
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Chrome on Android shows lines]

Comment: How big is the image...it looks like background bleed. Perhaps `background-size:20px`  ?

Comment: Heh, ok, that worked once I changed the background size to smaller size than the 100%. Thanks!